# Does Qt Designer or associated Qt tool have a global find-and-replace functionality for the xml formatted *.ui files?

Tags: python, xml, qt, pyside, qt-designer

My specific problem right now is relates to a roughly 4,800 line `.ui` file that I’ve created in *Qt Designer* in which I need to do some basic refactoring (renaming widgets). I convert the `.ui` file to a python file via `pyside-uic`.  I’ve gone over the *Qt Designer* documentation enough to convince myself with 95% certainty that it is not possible to do a global find-and-replace of widget names, or parts of names, from within *Qt Designer* itself. For example:

```
Step 1) Find 'pushButton'
Step 2) Replace with 'btn'
Step 3) Result is, i.e., 'pushButtonFooBarFooBar' gets renamed 'btnFooBarFooBar'
```

My first hope lies in that remaining 5% uncertainty from my document search of Qt Designer.  If I’ve missed something that provides this functionality I will be elated.  And I will abandon looking at more elaborate solutions using scripts and/or text editors.  In the big picture, had I better planned my naming scheme about 4,800 lines of code ago I wouldn’t have this problem now.

So my question, simply put, is:

> Is there a global find-and-replace functionality within Qt Designer or
>   associated Qt tools, and if so how is it invoked?

Comment: No, there isn't. But surely it would be quite easy to write a one-off python script to do this. It's only xml, after all.

Comment: @ekhumoro, that's what I figured.  I'm guessing python's xlm module would be a good starting point, I've just never used it or worked with xml much in general.  It does seem like its format would be amenable to what I need to do.  Is that the starting point you would suggest, reading up on python's xml module and creating a python script based off of that?

Comment: Before I did that, I think I would just see what could be done using search and replace in a text editor. Or maybe write a script using regular expressions, if you don't know xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a global find-and-replace functionality within Qt Designer or associated Qt tools, and if so how is it invoked?

No. But since XML is a text file, you are more than welcome to do a text search-and-replace in your favorite editor. E.g. using regexps replace `"pushButton([a-zA-Z0-9_$]*)"` with `"btn$1"`.

Unfortunately, Qt Creator doesn't offer a regexp capture replace function, but other editors surely do.

Comment: Hmm, when considering this solution I didn't even think about the possibility of using regular expressions.  That's ignoring a pretty powerful tool on my part I guess :(  This may be the easiest solution I'll find.  As a side note; Unless I'm the only one who thinks this functionality would be useful, this seems like a pretty major omission from the otherwise awesome Qt Designer program.

Comment: Qt Designer != Qt Creator :)

Comment: Ha, I didn't even catch that!